# Required All Checked boxes to be display from one form to another with "," seperation

Tags: javascript, html

I have issue with to show All Checked boxes to be display from one form to another with "," separation.

Presently below script is working to show only one checked box

```
<html>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<input name="items[]" id="item1" type="checkbox" value="item1" checked>
<input name="items[]" id="item2" type="checkbox" value="item2">
<input name="items[]" id="item3" type="checkbox" value="item3">

<input type="button" border="2" onClick="checkedBox();" >
</form>

<form id="form2">

<p id="view" id="view">Display Here</p>


</form>
<script>

    function checkedBox() {
        var input = document.querySelector('input[name="items[]"]:checked').value;
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = input;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please assist me to display all checked boxes, ex: if item 1 and 2 selected, should view as "item1 , item2"

Comment: use querySelectorAll() instead of querySelector()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector then loop through each element and get its value

try this :

```js
function checkedBox() {
  document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = "";
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="items[]"]:checked');
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("view").innerHTML += input[i].value;
    if(i!=(input.length-1)) {
      document.getElementById("view").innerHTML += ",";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input name="items[]" id="item1" type="checkbox" value="item1" checked>
  <input name="items[]" id="item2" type="checkbox" value="item2">
  <input name="items[]" id="item3" type="checkbox" value="item3">

  <input type="button" border="2" onClick="checkedBox();">
</form>

<form id="form2">

  <p id="view" id="view">Display Here</p>


</form>
```

Comment: this is working, is there is any way to use "," between only, cause if I select item1 only, result is "item1," if select all 3 items result is item1,item2,item3,

Comment: Updated my answer try now

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkedBox() {
    var a=  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
     var b=  [].slice.call(a);
      var c="";
      b.forEach(function(a){
      c += a.value+",";
      })
  document.getElementById("view").innerHTML=c.slice(0, -1);;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<input name="items[]" id="item1" type="checkbox" value="item1" checked>
<input name="items[]" id="item2" type="checkbox" value="item2">
<input name="items[]" id="item3" type="checkbox" value="item3">

<input type="button" border="2" onClick="checkedBox();" >
</form>

<form id="form2">

<p id="view" id="view">Display Here</p>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead, it is showing all 3 items without selecting. and it is fixed with below changes "<script>

    function checkedBox() {
    var a=  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="items[]"]:checked');
     var b=  Array.prototype.slice.call(a);
      var c="";
      b.forEach(function(a){
      c += a.value;
      })
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML=c;
    }
    </script>"

Comment: fix : `var a=  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');`

Comment: Specifically you need ``var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="items[]"]:checked');`` Otherwise it would show all checkboxes...

Comment: but required "," between each items, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>

    function checkedBox() {
        var input = document.querySelector('input[name="items[]"]:checked');
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
           document.getElementById("view").innerHTML += input[i].value + ",";
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkedBox() {
    let input = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="items[]"]:checked');
    let countInput = input.length;
    let inputValues = []

    if(countInput > 0){
        for(let i =0; i < countInput; i++){
            inputValues.push(input[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = inputValues.join(',');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check here https://jsbin.com/xemijacexe/edit?html,output

if it will not work let me know